# Can we add $NF$ to Ackermann's set theory?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, new-foundations

Can we simply add stratified comprehension $SF$ to axioms of Ackermann's set theory $Ack$?

> Is there a clear argument of inconsistency involved with such addition? supposing that $NF$ and $Ack$ are consistent of course.

Comment: It is not even known that $NF$ is consistent, right?

Comment: Yes but the argument is relative, if we suppose NF and Ack to be consistent, then is their blend consistent. By the way this question supposedly do have a positive answer according to Holmes, although he didn't write up the full formal proof, but the sketch of the proof is there and it seems convincing.

Comment: So you want to, from a model of $Ack$ and a model of $NF$, construct a model of $NF+Ack$?

Comment: Yes, something like that!